# Pandas : Replace old column values and plot new column values with respect to equations

Tags: python, pandas, csv

In a CSV file, I have three columns z,x,y where 'z' column is used to groupby x and y columns and will be plotted w.r.t 'z'. Below is the table for z,x,y.

```html
z       x         y
23 1,75181E-07 6,949512
23 8,88901E-07 6,963877
23 1,61279E-05 7,293052
23 5,35262E-05 8,135064
23 8,56942E-05 8,903738
23 0,000114883 9,579907
23 0,01068653 211,0798
23 0,01070811 211,3568
23 0,0107263   211,5871
23 0,01074606 211,8401
23 0,01076813 212,1311
23 0,01078525 212,3436
40 1,75181E-07 6,949513217
40 8,889E-07   6,96388319
40 1,61277E-05 7,293169621
40 5,35248E-05 8,135499439
40 0,00029527 13,63721607
40 0,000319049 14,1825142
40 0,000340228 14,69608917
40 0,014110191 252,3893548
40 0,014132366 252,5804547
40 0,014155023 252,8030254
40 0,014180293 253,0374241
40 0,014202693 253,1983821
40 0,014226167 253,4140887
40 0,014251631 253,6566835
40 0,014272699 253,8120535
```

Now I need to replace the 'x' and 'y' columns with new values say 'x1' and 'y1' by an equation: x1 = ln(1 + x) and y1 = y*(1+x) and w.r.t. same 'z' column I should plot x1 and y1.

I have tried the below code and I am able to see my new values but not able to plot with new values.

```html
import csv
import os
import tkinter as tk
import sys
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np

def readCSV(self):
        x=[]   # Initializing empty lists to store the 3 columns in csv
        y=[]
        z=[]
        global df
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        df = pd.read_csv(self.filename, error_bad_lines=False)   #Reading CSV file using pandas
        read = csv.reader(df, delimiter = ",")
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax= fig.add_subplot(111)
        df.set_index('x', inplace=True)  #Setting index
        line = df.groupby('z')['y'].plot(legend=True,ax=ax)   #grouping and plotting
        cursor = datacursor(line)
        gdf= df[df['z'] == 23]
        x=np.asarray(gdf.index.values)
        y=np.asarray(gdf['y'].values)
        x1 = np.log(1+x)
        y1 = y * (1 + x)

        
        df.set_index('x1', inplace=True)  #Setting new index
        line = df.groupby('z')['y1'].plot(legend=True,ax=ax)   #grouping and plotting for new values
        cursor = datacursor(line)
        gdf= df[df['z'] == 23]
        x1=np.asarray(gdf.index.values)
        print ("x1:",x1)
        y1=np.asarray(gdf['y1'].values)
        print ("y1:",y1)
        ax1 = ax.twinx()
        ax.grid(True)
        ax.set_ylim(0,None)
        ax.set_xlim(0,None)
        align_yaxis(ax, y.max(), ax1, 1)
        plt.show()
```

I am getting error in this line "df.set_index('x1', inplace=True)"
as keyerror : x1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You must assign `x1` adn 'y1' to the dataframe to be able to assign either of them to `index`:

```
x=np.asarray(df.index.values)
y=np.asarray(df['y'].values)
df['x1'] = np.log(1+x)
df['y1'] = y * (1+x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this but I am getting keyerror in 'x'

Comment: Yeah, that's because you moved it to index. Try rearranging your lines a bit

Comment: Yes I got but to make it simple where i need to edit inorder to plot only my new values x1 and y1.

Comment: @Kumar I changed the post 10 minutes ago, you'll see the difference.

Comment: I tried with the edited one but getting an error: Length of values does not match length of index